# Unable to connect to VPN through OpenVPN app

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have imported the `.ovpn` file, but when I try to connect I get the following error:

```
OpenVPN core error: option_error: cannot connect via TCP-based proxy 
because no TCP server entries exist in profile.
```

I have not messed with my phone in anyway (root, etc). It is just as I bought it, if that helps.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: To me it looks like a problem with the profile you imported.

Comment: @AndyYan, I'm not too sure what exactly constitutes the profile. All I imported was the .ovpn file. Do you mean that there is an error in that file?

Comment: Yeah, but that config file doesn't look like it's meant for users to edit (I started to use OpenVPN just recently, too). If someone else supplied that file to you, maybe ask him to double-check it.